# Is there any difference in using %f, %e, %g, %E or %G with scanf?

Tags: c, floating-point, scanf

In C, is there any difference in the format specifiers %f, %e, %g, %E and %G when used to read into a float variable with scanf? That is, will the behaviour of the code snippet

```
float x;
scanf("%<one of f, e, g, E, G>", &x);
```

ever depend on the choice of the specifier?

I first supposed that %f would only interpret decimal notation correctly, and %e would only interpret scientific notation correctly, but on my system, each of them works fine in either case. But maybe my system is just liberal...

I couldn't find any definite statement about this in my books or on the web...

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Thanks - this reference is on C++, that's why I didn't fully trust it before... Edited my question now, adding "C"

Comment: The POSIX page for [`fscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) reflects the C standard and adds some (carefully marked) extensions.  It says that conversion specifiers `a`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `A`, `E`, `F`, `G` all handle floating point numbers in any of the formats.  Exponents are always accepted (but never required). Decimal points are accepted but not required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The above answer refers to C++, but the same is true for C.

From "7.19.6.2 The fscanf function" in the ["Final version of the C99 standard with corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included, formatted as a draft"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (link copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99):

> **a,e,f,g**
>   Matches an optionally signed floating-point number, infinity,
>   or NaN, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence
>   of the strtod function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer
>   to floating.
>
> The conversion specifiers **A, E, F, G,** and **X** are also valid and
>   behave the same as, respectively, **a, e, f, g,** and **x**.

So `%f, %e, %g, %E, %G` all behave identically when *scanning* numbers, as you experienced.

Comment: What about printing them ?

Answer (score 2):

`f,e,g` all are for Floating point number

From the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/):-

> A series of decimal digits, optionally containing a decimal point,
>   optionally preceeded by a sign (+ or -) and optionally followed by the
>   e or E character and a decimal integer (or some of the other sequences
>   supported by strtod). Implementations complying with C99 also support
>   hexadecimal floating-point format when preceded by 0x or 0X.

Also check this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) which says that it(`f,e,g`) matches a floating-point number.

Answer (score 1):

C displays both float and double variables to six decimal places. This does NOT refer to the precision (accuracy) of which the number is actually stored, only how many decimal places `printf()` uses to display these variable types.

The following program illustrates how the different data types are declared and displayed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    float   a = 23.567;
    double  b = 11e+23;

    printf("Float variable is %f\n", a);
    printf("Double variable is %e\n", b);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Float variable is 23.567000
Double variable is 11.000000e23
```

Answer (score 1):

`%f` prints the number as a decimal floating point number, e.g. 214.52. `%e` prints the number in scientific notation, e.g. 214.52e+2. `%g` prints the number in the shortest among two, e.g. In the above two examples, if I want to print the number through %g then it would be 214.52 but not the 2.145e+2 as it is longer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float f=214.52;   
    printf("%f\n",f); // 214.520004
    printf("%e\n",f); // 2.145200e+02
    printf("%g\n",f); // 214.52
}
```

Answer (score 0):

base on @Sameer Sharma answer

```
$ cat test.c 
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{

float f=12.5123;

    printf("%f\n",f);
    printf("%e\n",f);
    printf("%g\n",f);
}
```

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
12.512300
1.251230e+01
12.5123
```

Answer (score -1):

```
%i=defaults for decimals
%u=gives the memory address of the variable
%p=gives the value of pointer
%e=gives the scientific notation
%g=handles large floating numbers
```